# GitHub Actions - How to build project in sub-directory

Tags: github-actions

I'm using GitHub Actions to build my project but my Dart project is in a sub-directory in the repository. The Action script can't find my `pubspec.yaml` and get the dependencies.

How can I point my GitHub Action to look for the source code in a sub-directory within my repository?

```
. (root of my GitHub repository)
└── dart_project
    ├── pubspec.yaml   <-- Git Hub action must point to this sub-dir
└── node_project
    ├── packages.json
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in "/__w/<my_project_path>".
##[error]Process completed with exit code 66.
```

This is the `dart.yml` file auto-generated by GitHub.

```
name: Dart CI

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    container:
      image:  google/dart:latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: pub get
    - name: Run tests
      run: pub run test
```

[image]

Answer (score 117, accepted):

If I understand your needs, you need the `pub` steps to run as if you'd done a `cd dart_project` first, right? Add the [`working-directory`](https://help.github.com/en/articles/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsworking-directory) parameter to your steps:

```
steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v1
- name: Install dependencies
  run: pub get
  working-directory: dart_project
- name: Run tests
  run: pub run test
  working-directory: dart_project
```

If you want to apply it to every step, use the tag `defaults`

```yaml
defaults:
  run:
    working-directory: dart_project
```

I believe that should be all you need.

Comment: I use this as a `default` run parameter, e.g. 

`defaults:\n\s\srun:\n\s\s\s\sworking-directory: sub-directory-name`. I added escape characters to indicate the document/syntax structure as this certainly doesn't warrant an additional answer.

Comment: `working-directory` appears deprecated in `v3`, what's the workaround instead?

Answer (score 36):

You can configure a `working-directory` on the step level for this purpose.
You can also configure a default directory for the steps. Defaults can be on job or global level.

Example on step level.

```yaml
jobs:
  build:
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: pub get
        working-directory: dart_project
      - name: Run tests
        run: pub run test
        working-directory: dart_project
```

Example on job level. This reduces duplication on the job level. This is suited for a job that is working on a sub-directory.

```yaml
jobs:
  build:
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: dart_project
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: pub get
      - name: Run tests
        run: pub run test
```

Example on global level. This reduces duplication on the global level. This is suited when all jobs in the workflow file are for a project located in a sub-directory.

```yaml
defaults:
  run:
    working-directory: dart_project
jobs:
  build:
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: pub get
      - name: Run tests
        run: pub run test
```