# GitHub Actions deploy error when using 'working-directory' option for Node.js app in subfolder, and zip/unzip artifact steps

Tags: node.js, azure-web-app-service, github-actions, cicd, kudu

I have a simple Node.js server that I'm deploying to Azure App Service using the following workflow in GitHub Actions. It includes artifact zip and unzip steps as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69402502/197591), to improve deployment performance.

```yaml
name: Build and deploy Node.js app to Azure Web App - myapp

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Node.js version
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: '16.x'

      - name: npm install, build, and test
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run build --if-present
          npm run test --if-present

      - name: Zip artifact for deployment
        run: zip release.zip ./* -r

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: node-app
          path: release.zip

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'nodetest'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: node-app

      - name: Unzip artifact for deployment
        run: unzip release.zip

      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: 'myapp'
          slot-name: 'nodetest'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_9E52572382474FD2A31555D64BEBCB1D }}
          package: .
```

This works fine. However, I must move the code into subfolder 'Server' of my repo, which means I must change the workflow according to the answers to [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57806624/197591). I must add the `working-directory` option to the `defaults`.

Also, as per [here](https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact/issues/232#issuecomment-1065422577), the upload step doesn't use `working-directory`, so I have to explicitly specify the path for this step.

My workflow now looks like this:

```yaml
name: Build and deploy Node.js app to Azure Web App - myapp

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: Server

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Node.js version
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: '16.x'

      - name: npm install, build, and test
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run build --if-present
          npm run test --if-present

      - name: Zip artifact for deployment
        run: zip release.zip ./* -r

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: node-app
          path: Server/release.zip

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'nodetest'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: node-app

      - name: Unzip artifact for deployment
        run: unzip release.zip

      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: 'myapp'
          slot-name: 'nodetest'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_9E52572382474FD2A31555D64BEBCB1D }}
          package: .
```

Probably not relevant, but I should mention that I have to set `PROJECT=Server` in the App Service application settings as per [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Customizing-deployments#using-app-settings-instead-of-a-deployment-file).

During the 'Deploy to Azure Web App' step, an error occurs. These are the logs:

```
Run azure/webapps-deploy@v2
  with:
    app-name: myapp
    slot-name: test
    publish-profile: ***
    package: .
Package deployment using ZIP Deploy initiated.
Updating submodules.
Preparing deployment for commit id '3fa8fc89-4'.
Generating deployment script.
Using the following command to generate deployment script: 'azure site deploymentscript -y --no-dot-deployment -r "/tmp/zipdeploy/extracted" -o "/home/site/deployments/tools" --basic --sitePath "/tmp/zipdeploy/extracted/Server"'.
The site directory path: ./Server
Generating deployment script for Web Site
Generated deployment script files
Running deployment command...
Command: "/home/site/deployments/tools/deploy.sh"
Handling Basic Web Site deployment.
Error: From directory doesn't exist
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
Kudu Sync failed
\n/opt/Kudu/Scripts/starter.sh "/home/site/deployments/tools/deploy.sh"
Deployment Failed.
Error: Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
Error: Deployment Failed with Error: Package deployment using ZIP Deploy failed. Refer logs for more details.
App Service Application URL: http://myapp-test.azurewebsites.net
```

The problem appears to be `From directory doesn't exist` (I found this in the Kudu code [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/KuduSync/blob/master/lib/FileUtils.ts#L17)). But I can't see why this is happening.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The files must be unzipped to the same folder as where they were zipped from in the repo. It could also be because of the `PROJECT` setting.

Either way, I solved this by adding `-d Server` to the `unzip` command.

It's worth noting that if the path is more than one level deep, the following step must be inserted before the unzip step:

```yaml
- name: Create folder
  run: mkdir -p ParentFolder/Server
```

Comment: I didn't notice in your OG question that you had `Server` in front of the path for `actions/upload-artifact@v2`, so note to anyone else who didn't know `actions/upload-artifact@v2` doesn't account for `working-directory` as its not a [*run* command](https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact/issues/196#issuecomment-834291140)